# How to enable Audience targeting in survey list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, survey-list, audience-targeting

I have created the survey list in SharePoint 2013.I need to apply the audience targeting for the survey.So I enabled the audience targeting, I'm not sure how it will work, whether It will work for each question or each survey? Please Clear me

Answer (score 2):

Target Audience for Survey works same as it works for other list/library.

Please refer below link to get more idea:

[Target content to specific audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Comment: in survey list the audience targeting column works as survey question.it will appear in respond to survey page.

Answer (score 1):

The target audience for Survey list works odd with default settings. It is coming up on survey question. I went with different approach solved my problem to avoid the user to answer from the page.

- Went to the Survey List "NewForm.aspx" In my case it is "<>Lists/EmployeeSurvey/NewForm.aspx"
- Edit page
- Edit web part properties.
- nder Advanced settings there is a Target Audience settings where I adding people.

Other approach I come across if it requires to show survey list for only few users

- Go to List settings
- Go to permissions for this list
- I broke the inherited permissions and added required users.

Either of approaches works for me.

Comment: Audience targeting under advanced mode in web part properties is only applicable for whole list.I need this as separate item.

Answer (score 1):

Click the list or library that contains the item you want to target.

For SharePoint Online, click Settings, and click List Settings or Document Library Settings.Select the Enable audience targeting check box

This link will help you more !

```
    https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-
audiences-
33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293
```